# Having 419 Ajax error in LARAVEL, how can i solve it?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I would really appreciate some help with this. I tried tons of solutions as posted in this forum, but I cannot get it to work

**My ajax call is something like**

```
        $('#ref').blur(function(){
    var ref = $('#ref').val();
    var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
    $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('refcheck')}}",
       method: "POST",
       date: {ref:ref, _token,_token},
       success:function (result) {
           if (result==0){
            $('.referror').html('<label class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Invalid Sposor Id</label>');
                $('.referror').slideDown();
                $('#ref').addClass('has-error');
        }
    }
    })
    });
```

**In Route**

```
    Route::post('/login/refcheck', 'CheckRegistraion@refCheck')->name('refcheck');
```

**And controller**

```
    function refCheck(Request $request){
        return 0;
    }
```

**My login.blade.php is**

```
        <form class="form-contact-warp form-calc-ship cb-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                 @csrf
    <input id="ref" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('ref') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Sponsor" type="text" name="ref" value="@if (request()->has('ref'))
{{request()->ref}}
@elseif(request()->has('ref')=='')
admin
@endif" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
<div class="errordiv referror"></div>
```

**I am getting this error**

POST http://localhost/metazone/public/login/refcheck 419 (unknown status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date: {ref:ref, _token:_token},

Comment: Thanks kerdouchi mohamed! Can't believe i made mistake like this..:)

Comment: Glad that you got your answer, FYI 419 error is all about csrf in laravel that may help in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have several typos. Try below

```
data: {ref:ref, _token:_token},
```

If it still give 419, do `console.log(_token)` to make sure your csrf token is valid

Comment: Thanks Michael Nguyen!